# Cannot make the tables across two columns float

Tags: tables, ieeetran

I am unable to get Table I in between the two lipsum paragraph no matter I tried [h], [!h], and other options. I have no problem w/ {table} but {table*} seems not respecting the options of positioning?

PS: Pls forgive/ignore the oversized pkg suit which is the current set I'm using. You are very welcome to comment on the pkg set.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

%\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
%\usepackage{bibentry}  
\usepackage{xcolor,soul,framed} %,caption
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{cite}

\colorlet{shadecolor}{yellow}
% \usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./pdf/}{./photo/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}

\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
%Mathabx do not work on ScribTex => Removed
%\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mdwmath}
% \usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{diagrams={nodes={inner sep=1pt}}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
    positioning,
    overlay-beamer-styles,
    shapes.geometric,
    decorations.text}
\usepackage{appendix}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}

\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}

%\bstctlcite{IEEE:BSTcontrol}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}

% extra packages
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\def \subFigJustEye{0.4\textwidth}
\def \subFigJust{0.55\textwidth}%this actually defines the justification. The previous name is "subFigJust"
\def \subGraphWidth{0.7\linewidth}
\def \FigWidth{80mm}%80mm is too large. 0. 7\linewidth is recommended. 
% \captionsetup[figure]{justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false,font=small,labelfont={},name={Fig. },labelsep=period}
% \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering,font=small}
% \usepackage{balance}
% \usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{listings}
% \usepackage{subfig}
% strike through elements in MA
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
% strike through text
\usepackage{cancel}
%% One column equation
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,lipsum}%lipsum: filler text. 
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}
\usepackage{cuted}
\setlength\stripsep{3pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}

%% Braces over matrix
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{diagrams={nodes={inner sep=1pt}}}
% \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
                positioning,
                overlay-beamer-styles,
                shapes.geometric,
                decorations.text}
% \usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
% \usepackage{adjustbox}
% \usepackage[cal=mt,scr=kp]{mathalpha}
% \usepackage{bm}
% \usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\DeclareMathOperator{\co}{co}
% restore pdf in dark theme
%  \usepackage{xcolor}
% \pagecolor[rgb]{0,0,0} %black
% \color[rgb]{0.5,0.5,0.5} %grey 
\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{float}

%=== TITLE & AUTHORS ====================================================================
\begin{document}
\bstctlcite{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol}

\section{Introduction}  
\lipsum[1]

\begin{table*}[!h]
\caption{EH, EW, RHM, RWM, and REM of Ch1, Ch2, and Ch3}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
        Channel & EH_{sub1} (mV) & EW_{sub1} (ps) & EH_{sub2} (mV) & EW_{sub2} (ps) & EH_{sub3} (mV) & EW_{sub3} (ps) & RHM & RWM & REM \\ \hline
        1 & 61.20 & 31.64 & 64.28 & 32.96 & 57.76 & 31.64 & 0.107 & 0.041 & 0.074 \\ \hline
        2 & 62.49 & 32.96 & 64.36 & 32.96 & 58.33 & 32.96 & 0.098 & 0.000 & 0.049 \\ \hline
        3 & 22.36 & 23.73 & 66.05 & 29.00 & 28.59 & 26.37 & 1.120 & 0.200 & 0.660 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:ch123_rem}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table*}[h]
\caption{EH, EW, RHM, RWM, and REM of Ch4, and Ch5}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
       Channel & EH_{sub1} (mV) & EW_{sub1} (ps) & EH_{sub2} (mV) & EW_{sub2} (ps) & EH_{sub3} (mV) & EW_{sub3} (ps) & RHM & RWM & REM \\ \hline
        4 & 404.98 & 35.60 & 466.00 & 36.91 & 462.35 & 35.60 & 0.137 & 0.036 & 0.087  \\ \hline
        5 & 359.85 & 35.60 & 371.36 & 35.60 & 369.36 & 35.60 & 0.031 & 0.000 & 0.016  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:ch45_rem}
\end{table*}
% \begin{table*}[!h]
% \caption{EH, EW, RHM, RWM, and REM of Ch4, and Ch5}
%     \centering
%     \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
%     \hline
%        Channel & EH_{sub1} (mV) & EW_{sub1} (ps) & EH_{sub2} (mV) & EW_{sub2} (ps) & EH_{sub3} (mV) & EW_{sub3} (ps) & RHM & RWM & REM \\ \hline
%         4 & 404.98 & 35.60 & 466.00 & 36.91 & 462.35 & 35.60 & 0.137 & 0.036 & 0.087  \\ \hline
%         5 & 359.85 & 35.60 & 371.36 & 35.60 & 369.36 & 35.60 & 0.031 & 0.000 & 0.016  \\ \hline
%     \end{tabular}
%     \label{tab:ch45_rem}
% \end{table*}


%   \clearpage  
%   \section*{References}
%   \bibliography{reference}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,Bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: spanning tables can not be inline so `\begin{table*}[!h]` does not allow the table anywhere as it does not allow `t`

Comment: do you _really_ use all those packages in a single article? both pstricks and tikz at the same time for example?? it's  really bad idea to include packages you don't use. I would remove _all_ the pakages, then just add them as needed

Comment: your example produces `! LaTeX Error: Command \appendices already defined.`  also `! Missing $ inserted`

Comment: your example (if we ignore the error messages) has no text after the table, so there are no columns for it to span. try `\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c@{\hspace{4cm}}c}
    aa&bbb\\
    aa&bbb\\
    aa&bbb\\
    aa&bbb\\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{xxx}
\end{table*}

\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}`

Comment: Thanks, David. That's what I suspect. I would say this is a nice feature to have, isn't it? How can I file a ticket with the Latex maintainer? Sorry to bother you but I googled and didn't get any useful info.

Comment: Yes, the missing $ error should be due to the subscripts in the column head of the table. They did not seem to produce real problems so I didn't spend time to correct them. Should be ok I guess?

Comment: Thanks again for the comments and the example. Really appreciate it. Regarding the necessary pkgs, even though some of them are redundant, it should not lead to real problems if keeping them there? I do not have an extensive knowledge of all these pkgs so my strategy so far is to use the current common set of pkgs as long as it works. In case of conflict emerges, then I set off to fix them. I guess the risk of such a strategy might be in the future, the possibility of conflict will be significantly larger than a pruned set of pkgs?

Answer (score 1):

No need to employ `table*` environments: With a bit of planning, both "wide" tables can actuallly be made to fit inside a column. Note that quite a bit of horizontal space can be saved by getting rid of the multitudes of vertical rules.

I can't help but remark that many of the packages you load are obsolete and/or harmful. For instance, you should *not* be loading the `caption` and `subcaption` packages when using the `IEEEtran` document class.

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum,booktabs}
 
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}  
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{table}[!h]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTeX figure out intercol. whitespace amounts

\caption{EH, EW, RHM, RWM, and REM of Ch1, Ch2, and Ch3}
\label{tab:ch123_rem}

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l *{9}{c}}
\toprule
Ch. & EH\textsubscript{sub1} & EW\textsubscript{sub1} & EH\textsubscript{sub2} & EW\textsubscript{sub2} & EH\textsubscript{sub3} & EW\textsubscript{sub3} & RHM & RWM & REM \\ 
    & (mV) & (ps) & (mV) & (ps) & (mV) & (ps) & & & \\
\midrule
1 & 61.20 & 31.64 & 64.28 & 32.96 & 57.76 & 31.64 & 0.107 & 0.041 & 0.074 \\ 
2 & 62.49 & 32.96 & 64.36 & 32.96 & 58.33 & 32.96 & 0.098 & 0.000 & 0.049 \\ 
3 & 22.36 & 23.73 & 66.05 & 29.00 & 28.59 & 26.37 & 1.120 & 0.200 & 0.660 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    
\bigskip
\caption{EH, EW, RHM, RWM, and REM of Ch4, and Ch5}
\label{tab:ch45_rem}

\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l *{9}{c}}
\toprule
Ch. & EH\textsubscript{sub1} & EW\textsubscript{sub1} & EH\textsubscript{sub2} & EW\textsubscript{sub2} & EH\textsubscript{sub3} & EW\textsubscript{sub3} & RHM & RWM & REM \\ 
    & (mV) & (ps) & (mV) & (ps) & (mV) & (ps) & & & \\
\midrule
4 & 404.98 & 35.60 & 466.00 & 36.91 & 462.35 & 35.60 & 0.137 & 0.036 & 0.087  \\ 
5 & 359.85 & 35.60 & 371.36 & 35.60 & 369.36 & 35.60 & 0.031 & 0.000 & 0.016  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    
\end{table}

\lipsum[2][1-4]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the super helpful answer

Comment: @ShermanChen, if answer is *super helpful* than you should at list upvote it or even accept it (by clicking on up-triangle and checkmark at top left side of answer)!